# Pin a post to the top of a page, other than the home page

Tags: sticky-post

I'm using a static home page, so my posts go to a different page. How can I pin a post to the top of the page the posts go to (not the home page)? Originally I thought it was as easy as using the edit page feature, so I typed what I wanted, but apparently when you change to a static home page and redirect your posts to a different page, it overrides what you wrote in the edit page.

Comment: Do you mean a [sticky post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)?

Comment: Please use more information like what you mean by "what you wrote in edit page". Is this Blog page where all posts are listed?

Answer (score -1):

A 'sticky post' (as mentioned by @milo ) is what you want to do for the post to be 'sticky' at the top of the posts page.

(Answer added to get this question out of the 'unanswered' queue.)